# Setting file permissions on a large amount of files using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, file-permissions, windows-scripting

I have two files, one with a list of the security groups and one with the corresponding folder path. All I need to do is loop through these files and apply the correct security group recursive RW access to the correct folder.

So security group on line 1 would apply to the folder on line 1.

Powershell script:

```bsh
foreach ($group in gc c:\temp\securitygroups.txt) {
    $rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule ($group, 'Modify','ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit', 'None', 'Allow')

    foreach ($folder in gc c:\temp\folders.txt) {
        $acl = Get-Acl $folder
        $acl.SetAccessRule($rule)
        Set-Acl $folder $acl
    }
}
```

`securitygroups.txt`:

```
securitygroup1
securitygroup2
securitygroup3
securitygroup4
securitygroup5
securitygroup6
securitygroup7
securitygroup8
securitygroup9
securitygroup10
```

`folders.txt`:

```
D:\shares\projects\project1
D:\shares\projects\project2
D:\shares\projects\project3
D:\shares\projects\project4
D:\shares\projects\project5
D:\shares\projects\project6
D:\shares\projects\project7
D:\shares\projects\project8
D:\shares\projects\project9
D:\shares\projects\project10
```

At the moment every security group in securitygroups.txt is being added to each folder in the list, this is not what I want, I want `securitygroup1` adding to `project1`,  `securitygroup2` adding to `project2` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read both files into variables, then use a `for` loop to iterate over both arrays at the same time:

```
$groups  = Get-Content 'c:\temp\securitygroups.txt'
$folders = Get-Content 'c:\temp\folders.txt'

for ($i=0; $i -lt $folders.Count; $i++) {
    $rule = New-Object Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule ($groups[$i], 'Modify', 'ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit', 'None', 'Allow')
    $acl = Get-Acl $folders[$i]
    $acl.SetAccessRule($rule)
    Set-Acl $folders[$i] $acl
}
```